Prophet Muhammad worship in Cave Hira
As per this hadith,
https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3
it is mentioned that "He used to go in seclusion in the cave of Hira where he used to worship (Allah alone) continuously for many days before his desire to see his family."
My question is what Prophet used to do in the cave as there was no concept of namaaz at that time. How and what he used to worship? Which surah and whatever relevant Prophet used to speak in the worship? What was his day like in the cave?

He was a Hanif, following the religion of Ibrahim AS. He worshiped Allah in the same way that Ibrahim AS did.

So if Prophet Muhammad used to pray in the same way as Prophet Abraham, then did he know of Prophet Abraham at his time during cave Hira? If yes, then how? Also, how did Prophet Abraham used to pray? Do we have any records for this?

Scholars like ibn Hajar in his Fath al-Barry interpreted this statement and especially the statement -at least in this chapter- (see for example here):
(In the following I'll be translating from Arabic language as these interpretations are mine even if I may use some tools like google-translate, take them with the necessary care!)

فيتحنث

which literally means:

then he throws away (his) sin(s)

as

هي بمعنى يتحنف ، أي : يتبع الحنفية وهي دين إبراهيم
referring to he follows the Hanif path, means: he was following the Hanafia the religion of Ibraheem ().

He also pointed at the riwaya of ibn Hishaam in his Sira book which used the later word instead of the first as mentioned in the hadith where az-Zuhri needed to explain by adding his own commentary saying:

فَيَتَحَنَّثُ فِيهِ ـ وَهُوَ التَّعَبُّدُ ـ

So the addition "ـ وَهُوَ التَّعَبُّدُ ـ" (meaning he used to worship) was an explanation of imam az-Zuhri.
Sheikh ibn 'Othaymeen actually was less focussed on the one interpretation and explained the worship as follows:

ولكن كيف يتعبد ، هل هو بإلهام ، أو بما بقي من شرائع إسماعيل في العرب أو بمقتضى الفطرة ؟.
كل هذه احتمالات ، ولكن لا شك أنه صلوات الله وسلامه عليه يشعر في هذا المكان بقربه من الله ، وتقربه إليه بما ألهمه الله إياه من الشرائع ، أو بما بقي من شريعة إسماعيل أو بالفطرة ، المهم أنه يتعبد . (source)
But how does he worship, is it by inspiration, or by what remains of the shari'a of Ismael among the Arabs, or by virtue of instinct (fitra)?
All of these are possibilities, but there is no doubt that in this place, may Allah’s prayers and peace be upon him, he feels his closeness to Allah, and his closeness to Him by what Allah inspired him with of the laws, or by what remains of the shari'a of Ismael, or by instinct. The important thing is that he worships.

This means Muhammad () has chosen seclusion in the cave of Hiraa' to seek refuge and closeness to Allah,with what he was inspired or knew/learnt from the good (non-pagan) practice of the Meccan's which had a basis in the Hanfia which was thought by Ibraheem.
This more general explanation was also expressed by ibn Hajar in his interpretation of another version of the hadith as compilled in Sahih al-Bukhari in the book of Tafsir on surat Iqra' (see for example here):

وله : ( قال : والتحنث التعبد ) هذا ظاهر في الإدراج ، إذ لو كان من بقية كلام عائشة لجاء فيه قالت ، وهو يحتمل أن يكون من كلام عروة أو من دونه ، ولم يأت التصريح بصفة تعبده ، لكن في رواية عبيد بن عمير عند ابن إسحاق " فيطعم من يرد عليه من المساكين "
And he said: (He said: And devotion is worship) This is apparent in the inclusion, because if it was from the rest of Aisha’s words, it would have included “she said”, and it is possible that it was from the words of Urwah or from someone other than that, and the description of his devotion was not explicitly mentioned, but in the narration of 'Ubayd ibn 'Umair with Ibn Ishaq “He feeds whoever comes to him from the poor”,
وجاء عن بعض المشايخ أنه كان يتعبد بالتفكر ، ويحتمل أن تكون عائشة أطلقت على الخلوة بمجردها تعبدا ، فإن الانعزال عن الناس ولا سيما من كان على باطل من جملة العبادة كما وقع للخليل - عليه السلام - حيث قال : إني ذاهب إلى ربي ، وهذا يلتفت إلى مسألة أصولية ، وهو أنه - صلى الله عليه وسلم - هل كان قبل أن يوحى إليه متعبدا بشريعة نبي قبله ؟
and it was reported from some of the sheikhs that he used to worship by contemplation, and it is possible that Aisha applied the term “seclusion” to worship alone, because isolation from people, especially those who are on falsehood, is part of worship, as happened to Al-Khalil - peace be upon him - when he said: "I will go to my Lord", and this turns to a fundamental issue, which is that was he - may Allah bless him and grant him peace - before revelation came to him worshipping according to the law of a prophet before him?
قال الجمهور : لا ، لأنه لو كان تابعا لاستبعد أن يكون متبوعا ، ولأنه لو كان لنقل من كان ينسب إليه . وقيل نعم واختاره ابن الحاجب ،
The majority said: No, because if he was a follower, it would be unlikely that he was followed, and because if he was, he would have transmitted from whomever he was attributed to. It was said yes and Ibn al-Hajib chose it,
واختلفوا في تعيينه على ثمانية أقوال :
and they differed in identifying it with eight sayings:
أحدها آدم حكاه ابن برهان ،
One of them is Adam (), narrated by ibn Burhan,
الثاني نوح حكاه الآمدي ،
the second is Noah (), narrated by al-Aamidi,
الثالث إبراهيم ذهب إليه جماعة واستدلوا بقوله تعالى أن اتبع ملة إبراهيم حنيفا ،
the third is Ibraheem (), a group went to it and they provided evidence with the words of Allah Almighty: “to follow the religion of Abraham, inclining toward truth,”
الرابع موسى ،
the fourth is Mosa(),
الخامس عيسى ،
the fifth is 'Isa (),
السادس بكل شيء بلغه عن شرع نبي من الأنبياء وحجته "أولئك الذين هدى الله فبهداهم اقتده" ،
the sixth is everything he has heard from the law of a prophet from the prophets and his proof is "Those are the ones whom Allah has guided, so from their guidance take an example.",
السابع الوقف واختاره الآمدي ، ولا يخفى قوة الثالث ولا سيما مع ما نقل من ملازمته للحج والطواف ونحو ذلك مما بقي عندهم من شريعة إبراهيم والله أعلم . وهذا كله قبل النبوة ، وأما بعد النبوة فقد تقدم القول فيه في تفسير سورة الأنعام .
the seventh is the stopping of interpretation and al-Amidi chose it, and the strength of the third is not hidden, especially with what was transmitted of his adherence to Hajj and Tawaf and the like of what remained with them from the shari'a of Ibraheem, and Allah knows best. And all of this was before the prophethood, and as for after the prophethood, the statement about it was presented in the interpretation of Surat al-An’am.

Note This is just a copy-paste + translation of Fath al-Barry I didn't check if ibn Hajar somehwere completed and added 8th view.

When you mentioned "...Hanafia the religion of Ibraheem", what does this mean? Isn't the religion of Ibraheem Islam as well? Please clarify.

All I get from your answer is that he used or tried to follow the teachings of the Prophets before him / he was inspired or knew/learnt from the good (non-pagan) practice of the Meccan's which had a basis in the Hanfia which was 'taught' by Ibraheem. But again the question comes that in those times, truth was nowhere and all the teachings or practices could have been corrupted/dubious no matter how good they were then does it mean that the Prophet went with his instincts?
It appears that there is no definite answer for my question.
